# Python 3.10 -sslv3 alert handhsake failure 997

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3

Python 3.10 increased default security setting of the TLS. the same below code is working in python 3.9 but throwing [SSL:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] (_ssl.c:997)

```
import requests
import urllib3
requests.package.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'ALL:@SECLEVEL=1'

headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
data = {
        'selct1':sel,
        'selct2':der
}
res = requests.get(url,data=data,headers=headers,verify=False)
```

I tried changing SecLevel to 1 , but still its failing.

Answer (score 2):

the issue gets resolved by downgrading the requests and urlib3 version. By default request 2.31 version gets installed which is causing this issue, after unistalling this version and used pip install request==2.24.0 which resolve the issue